# Not able to Login after editing common-auth file

Tags: login

I am trying to play around with PAM.

To start with, i am working with pam_tally module.

I added following line at the top in common-auth file in /etc/pam.d/

auth required pam_tally.so deny=3

After that i logged out.

Now when i try to login, access is denied even though password i enter is correct.

I edit common-auth file again using root account to remove the above mentioned line and i am able to login again.

Not able to understand why i am denied login after editing common-auth file even if password i enter is correct.

Please help

Comment: I had a very similar problem, and haven't gotten any help.  Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it happened, but I solved my similar issue by removing `deny=3` and using `sudo faillog -m 3` instead.